# Are there two gauri Kunds?

Tags: shiva-purana, skanda-purana, pilgrimage

Are there two gauri Kunds? Wikipedia says Gauri kunda is the base camp of Kedarnath trek
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauri_Kund
There's another gauri Kund on the route of Mount kailash surroundings, parikrama
https://www.lumle.com/placestogo/gauri-kund/